# Why does this error appears to me even I wrote the code right (according to a tutorial)?

Tags: java

```
C:\Users>javaC C:\Main.java
```

C:\Main.java:1: error: error while writing Main: C:\Main.class
public class Main {
^
1 error

Comment: Do you have write permission to `C:`?  In general one tends to do one's application development in a folder somewhere in user space, not in the root of the entire file system.  You might try making a folder under your `Documents` folder and developing there.

Comment: Please share the contents of *Main.java*.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that javac cannot create the compilation output `C:\Main.class`.

By default, a normal user does not have write access to the root of the C: drive. Create your class elsewhere (not directly in `C:\`), but for example in `C:\development`.